# Why was my US B2 visa rejected?

Tags: usa, visa-refusals

I applied for a US B2 visa with family (wife and 2 children), from Saudi Arabia. I hold a Pakistani passport. My case goes like this:

I submitted an employment certificate stating my per annum basic salary, 32,000 dollars with other benefits, a bank statement with almost 13,000 dollars in the account.

The officer disqualified me on account of that it doesn’t make sense that one can spend half of the yearly salary on their vacations. He barely asked me two questions about why I want to visit and where I will go in the US.

I have travelled to the UK, Europe and other places, and have a good traveling history. I mentioned three weeks of stay and 3 cities to visit. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Why did the officer think you were going to spend all of the money in the account on this one holiday?

Comment: I am also unable to understand why does he thinks so? I have been to Europe and covered 6 countries on my one vacation with the same salary and statements but haven’t spent all of my money, also he asked where i would go I mentioned three cities in states and he said it makes no sense you with a family of 3 persons can travel with this amount internationally and domestically.

Comment: Did he specifically mention he was rejecting the application because he believed you would be spending half your salary on your vacation? What information had you submitted on the DS160 form? Did you ever say/write that the trip would cost you $16000?

Comment: Yes . He said we are disqualified because our per annum salary is stated insufficient when i asked him to review my statement he stated that it doesn’t make sense for someone of spending full in vacation, also he said try another time may be the bext officer will grant you visa. I haven’t mentioned or stated by own in my interview that how much i will spend. He rejected us in seconds and didn’t even reviewed our other documents which was strong family ties

Comment: I wonder why he said that. 32000usd goes a long way. I've never spent $16000 on a vacation. That's crazy. You can apply for a freedom of information request to know more about what the officer exactly thought. He could've thought it was  $3200 instead of $32000?

Comment: If I wanted to re apply, what should be considered in next application? I don’t have specify plans but wanted to visit us in my next vacation. Shall I present them hotel booking in section of US contact in ds 160?

Comment: You ask why, and then you tell us why in the third paragraph.   Are you assuming he lied and you want us to GUESS the real reason?  My "guess" is the reason he told you.